# Manga/manhwa/manhua about a designer or developer who falls asleep and wakes up inside a game he was working on

Tags: story-identification, isekai, reincarnation

I am trying to find a manhua or manhwa where the main character is a designer or developer or something. He was working on a game when he fell asleep and the next moment he was in the game. He has many characters and all of them are max level; I think level 100. I can't remember its name; I read it months ago. If anyone knows, help me.
Sorry it was my fault for not explaining properly everything cause i also forget about everything but now i remember it's name was(My Disciples Are Super Gods)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour? Also, can you tell us anything more about what happens after the developer/designer wakes up inside the game? What you've given us so far is likely consistent with multiple different stories. If you can think of anything else, please add it to your question using the [edit] feature.

Comment: Not a manwha, but Deathmarch To The Parallel World Rhapsody has that premise.

Comment: @user153809 - If you're the same person who posted this question, it looks like you've created a second account, which is why you can't edit this question without other users' approval, or leave a comment here, like this one. You can fix this problem by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merging your new account with the previous one.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question. You can even accept it by clicking on the checkmark. :) Just please make it as complete of an answer as you'd have hoped to have received before, indicating *why* it is correct.

Comment: I'm going to put a placeholder answer in for now. Feel free to write your own and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 3):

The querent identified the work in question as *[My Disciples Are Super Gods](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-disciples-are-super-strong)*, aka *My Disciples Are Super Strong* or *Wo de Dizi Dou Chao Shen*.

[image: Front cover of My Disciples Are Super Strong]

> Ye Yang, an overworked employee at a game company, finds himself transmigrating into a game with maxed-out skills in all classes! Thus begins his life as an apathetic Sect Master who is also a full-level Sword Saint + cultivator + mage! The only downside is that his beautiful disciples keep pushing him to better himself each day...